# Drupal: How to show results in another page (PHP)

Tags: drupal

I need to know how to show results in another page in PHP. After much research in the files drupal site. The existence of a file "search-result.tpl.php"

So, how to show this in another page php?

search-result.tpl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for displaying a single search result.
 *
 * This template renders a single search result and is collected into
 * search-results.tpl.php. This and the parent template are
 * dependent to one another sharing the markup for definition lists.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $url: URL of the result.
 * - $title: Title of the result.
 * - $snippet: A small preview of the result. Does not apply to user searches.
 * - $info: String of all the meta information ready for print. Does not apply
 *   to user searches.
 * - $info_split: Contains same data as $info, split into a keyed array.
 * - $module: The machine-readable name of the module (tab) being searched, such
 *   as "node" or "user".
 * - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
 *   appears in the template.
 * - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
 *   the template.
 *
 * Default keys within $info_split:
 * - $info_split['type']: Node type (or item type string supplied by module).
 * - $info_split['user']: Author of the node linked to users profile. Depends
 *   on permission.
 * - $info_split['date']: Last update of the node. Short formatted.
 * - $info_split['comment']: Number of comments output as "% comments", %
 *   being the count. Depends on comment.module.
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of HTML class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 * - $title_attributes_array: Array of HTML attributes for the title. It is
 *   flattened into a string within the variable $title_attributes.
 * - $content_attributes_array: Array of HTML attributes for the content. It is
 *   flattened into a string within the variable $content_attributes.
 *
 * Since $info_split is keyed, a direct print of the item is possible.
 * This array does not apply to user searches so it is recommended to check
 * for its existence before printing. The default keys of 'type', 'user' and
 * 'date' always exist for node searches. Modules may provide other data.
 * @code
 *   <?php if (isset($info_split['comment'])): ?>
 *     <span class="info-comment">
 *       <?php print $info_split['comment']; ?>
 *     </span>
 *   <?php endif; ?>
 * @endcode
 *
 * To check for all available data within $info_split, use the code below.
 * @code
 *   <?php print '<pre>'. check_plain(print_r($info_split, 1)) .'</pre>'; ?>
 * @endcode
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_search_result()
 * @see template_process()
 */
?>
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean "show this in another page php"?

Answer (score 0):

What I believev you probably want to do is copy the search-result.tpl.php file to your themes directory and then modify it directly.

I do know that Drupal looks in your theme directory for template files first, which allows you to "override" core functionality without corrupting the system.

If you manage to fatally break the search-result.tpl.php file, you can just delete or rename it and get the original functionality back.